# 24 ^ 15 = 23 in bitwise operation

Tags: python-3.x

I tried "XOR"

```
In [124]: 3 ^ 6
Out[124]: 5

In [125]: 2 ^ 7
Out[125]: 5

In [126]: 24 ^ 15
Out[126]: 23
```

I am very confused about the result which seems no principles in it,
Could please provide any hints to understand it?

Comment: `011 ^ 110 = 101`, `010 ^ 111 = 101`, `00011000 ^ 00001111 = 00010111`.  Think binary (or use a programming calculator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise XOR (^) takes two bits and checks if they are different (e.g. one is 0 and the other is 1). If it is the case, it returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. So it is best to write the numbers in their binary representation and do the calculation for every digit (from left to right):

```
  011    -->   3
^ 110    --> ^ 6
-----        ---
  101    -->   5
```